# HDF5 struct with pointer array

Tags: c++, dataset, allocation, hdf5

I am trying to write a HDF5 file with a structure which contains an int and a float*

```
typedef struct s1_t {
int    a;
float *b;
} s1_t;
```

However, upon allocating the float* and putting values into it, I still can't output the data in my hdf5 file. I believe this is because the write function assumes that the compound data type is contiguous when a dynamically allocated array will not be. Is there any way around this problem by still using a pointer array?

```
    /*
 * This example shows how to create a compound data type with an array member,
 * and write an array which has the compound data type to the file.
 */
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "hdf5.h"

#define FILE          "DSwith_array_member.h5"
#define DATASETNAME   "ArrayOfStructures"
#define LENGTH        10
#define RANK          1
#define ARRAY_RANK    1
#define ARRAY_DIM     3 

int
main(void)
{

    /* First structure  and dataset*/
    typedef struct s1_t {
    int    a;
    //float  b[ARRAY_DIM];
    float *b;
    } s1_t;
    s1_t       s1[LENGTH];

    hid_t      s1_tid;     /* File datatype identifier */
    hid_t      array_tid; /* Array datatype handle */
    hid_t      file, dataset, space; /* Handles */
    herr_t     status;
    hsize_t    dim[] = {LENGTH};   /* Dataspace dimensions */
    hsize_t    array_dim[] = {ARRAY_DIM};   /* Array dimensions */

    int        i, j;

    /*
     * Initialize the data
     */
    for (i = 0; i< LENGTH; i++) {
        s1[i].a = i;
        s1[i].b = (float*)calloc(ARRAY_DIM, sizeof(float));
        for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_DIM; j++) {
             s1[i].b[j] = i+j;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Create the data space.
     */
    space = H5Screate_simple(RANK, dim, NULL);

    /*
     * Create the file.
     */
    file = H5Fcreate(FILE, H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

    /*
     * Create the array data type. 
     */
     array_tid = H5Tarray_create(H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT, ARRAY_RANK, array_dim);

    /*
     * Create the memory data type. 
     */
    s1_tid = H5Tcreate (H5T_COMPOUND, sizeof(s1_t));
    H5Tinsert(s1_tid, "a_name", HOFFSET(s1_t, a), H5T_NATIVE_INT);
    H5Tinsert(s1_tid, "b_name", HOFFSET(s1_t, b), array_tid);

    /* 
     * Create the dataset.
     */
    dataset = H5Dcreate(file, DATASETNAME, s1_tid, space, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

    /*
     * Wtite data to the dataset; 
     */
    status = H5Dwrite(dataset, s1_tid, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, s1);

    /*
     * Release resources
     */
    H5Tclose(s1_tid);
    H5Tclose(array_tid);
    H5Sclose(space);
    H5Dclose(dataset);
    H5Fclose(file);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right. Changing your structure to

```
typedef struct s1_t {
    int   a;
    float b[ARRAY_DIM];
} s1_t;
```

would work, but I guess you know that.

I can see two solutions:

1. Use a temporary buffer, like an array of the structure above, for writing.
2. Using a variable length array instead of an array for `b_name`.

#### Example using a variable length array for `b_name`

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "hdf5.h"

#define FILE          "DSwith_array_member.h5"
#define DATASETNAME   "ArrayOfStructures"
#define LENGTH        10
#define RANK          1
#define ARRAY_RANK    1
#define ARRAY_DIM     3 

typedef struct s1_t {
int    a;
float *b;
} s1_t;

typedef struct s1_buffer_t {
    int   a;
    hvl_t b;
} s1_buffer_t;

int main(void)
{
    s1_t       s1[LENGTH];
    hid_t      s1_tid;                          /* File datatype identifier */
    hid_t      file, dataset, space, vlen_tid;  /* Handles */
    hsize_t    dim[] = {LENGTH};                /* Dataspace dimensions */
    int        i, j;
    s1_buffer_t s1_buffer[LENGTH];
    for (i = 0; i< LENGTH; i++) {
        s1[i].a = i;
        s1[i].b = (float*)calloc(ARRAY_DIM, sizeof(float));
        for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_DIM; j++) {
             s1[i].b[j] = i+j;
        }
    }
    space = H5Screate_simple(RANK, dim, NULL);
    file = H5Fcreate(FILE, H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);
    vlen_tid = H5Tvlen_create(H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT);
    s1_tid = H5Tcreate(H5T_COMPOUND, sizeof(s1_buffer_t));
    H5Tinsert(s1_tid, "a_name", HOFFSET(s1_t, a), H5T_NATIVE_INT);
    H5Tinsert(s1_tid, "b_name", HOFFSET(s1_t, b), vlen_tid);
    dataset = H5Dcreate(file, DATASETNAME, s1_tid, space, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);
    for (i = 0; i < LENGTH; ++i)
    {
        s1_buffer[i].a = s1[i].a;
        s1_buffer[i].b.len = ARRAY_DIM;
        s1_buffer[i].b.p = s1[i].b;
    }
    H5Dwrite(dataset, s1_tid, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, s1_buffer);
    H5Tclose(s1_tid);
    H5Tclose(vlen_tid);
    H5Sclose(space);
    H5Dclose(dataset);
    H5Fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, you still need a temporary buffer but at least it only needs to store pointers (the `b` pointers from `s1`) and not arrays of size `ARRAY_DIM` as would be the case with solution 1 above.

Comment: I have tried implementing a variable array for b_name, but I keep running into an unhandled exception error when I try to call H5Dwrite(). Would you be able to provide me a simple example with b_name as a variable length array?

Comment: @foboi1122 I added an example.

Comment: thank you for the example, it's much more clear to me now. Is there a way to read this file directly into a standard structure? What I mean is when we call H5Dread, I read into a buffer that has the structure s1_buffer_t, however, s1_buffer type contains a hvl_t type array. In a standard data structure, I do not use these types of arrays. They are usually just floating arrays. So for now, I am doing a memcpy from the s1_buffer_t structure to my own similar struct which uses float *b instead of hvl_t b. However this ends up taking more ram because I have to hold the buffer and struct.

Comment: I know, I wish we could avoid the temporary buffer in this case but it doesn't seem possible. If you are using C++, you could encapsulate this in a class: store an array of `s1_buffer_t` but expose the interface of `s1_t`… It really depends on what is more critical in your application between read/write or use of the data.